# Qt QPSQL QSqlDatabase: named connection fails

Tags: qt, qsqldatabase

I am trying to have multiple QPSQL QSqlDatabase connections in my application.

When I use only one connection - default/ no name, - it works flawlessly.

But as soon as I try to create a *named* connection, it fails.

The error message is: "Driver not loaded".

This works:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
```

But this fails:

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL", "somestringhere");
```

The other properties are precisely the same: server, port, user name and password.
The only difference is in the 2nd parameter of the addDatabase method.

If I go back and forth, trying with or without the 2nd input parameter, the results are consistent: the connection is always working without the 2nd parameter and always fails with it.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a bug in QPSQL?

The app uses Qt 6.3.0 with Qt's MinGW-64 on Windows 10.

Comment: Please show the complete code - it works, you have a typo somewhere for sure.

Comment: ***The error message is: "Driver not loaded".*** Did you compile the driver? On windows it usually won't be in the binaries.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me. I kept digging and found the root cause of the problem. I posted it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root cause of the problem was in my multithreaded code.

Once I fixed that, the database connection started working as expected.

It is unfortunate that the error message was misleading (i.e., there was actually *nothing wrong* with the driver), but at least I found the problem and fixed.